# Blender 2.8 - How to fragment an object in cubes

Tags: modifiers

as the title suggests, I have doubts about how to quickly break up an object by dividing it into fragments in the shape of a cube.

Let me explain better with images:

This is the object on which to apply the subdivision:

[image]

At this point, I select a desired part of the object and separate it from the main object, creating an new separated object (in the
example I moved it only to show the subdivision and the different inside
material).

At the moment, with my basic knowledge, I selected the
desired faces, separating them with "P-by Selection". I then filled in
the missing faces, applying a different material manually (those colored in blue):

[image]

In turn I would like to divide the previously separated object into
many small cubes, with the "internal" faces already filled and with an assigned material:

[image]

To explain myself better, the function most similar to the one I would
like to obtain is the **Addon cell fracture**: in fact, using it, a
separated object is created for each fragment, the internal faces are
 created, and a desired material is applied inside, but it has the
**disadvantage** of creating irregular fragments, while I would like them all in the shape of a box (cube / rectangle).

[image]

Do you know any automatic functions that allow me to **split** specific parts of a mesh into **cube-shaped fragments**? A kind of "subdivide" but at the level of the object and not of the faces, which automatically creates the missing faces of the new objects created and associates it with a material of your choice. At the moment I can get the desired result but at the cost of spending a lot of time in the various manual steps, an automation of some kind would be fantastic!

I tried to experiment also with the "boolean" modifier, but it has the disadvantage of not "filling" the missing faces, of not creating new separate objects, etc ...

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use " > " unless you quote.

Comment: This might help... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141468/rigid-body-dynamic-animation-problem/141678#141678